# Shell script to find all functions that measure time

Tags: shell

I'm new to shell scripting. I'm trying to write a shell script that will find commands and functions which measure time both in shell and in C.
I would like to present the result in three columns - name of the function, man section number and a short description of the function.
I've found that I can find all functions and display them in the way I want using:

```
man -k time
```

Could someone please give me some pointers? How can I limit the results to only those functions that measure time in shell and C (not those that contain word 'time')?

Comment: why can't you use just `man time` or `man -a time`

Comment: `man` isn't going to find shell functions (it will find shell built-ins on some systems though). But determining *what* sort of `time` related function you are dealing with isn't exactly an automatic process.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Is this your actual goal or are you trying to solve some other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on unix.stackexchange.com 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

As you can see 1 is "user commands" these run in a shell - your shell commands
sections 2 and 3 are C system calls or C library functions

If you look at the man page sections there is a SYNOPSIS section

This gives a C language summary of the functions available.  There is usually
more information in the rest of the man page but parsing it out will not be obvious

So run `man -k time |egrep '\([23]\)'` and you will get all the C man page names from section 2 and 3.  Pipe that into awk or cut to get the first field and then feed that into man (without a k option) and this will give the content for each

To extract the SYNOPSIS section something like this might be good

```
man time| sed -n '/SYNOPSIS/,/DESCRIPTION/p'
```

Maybe running this with egrep '([123])' might be a better idea and just getting the SYNOPSIS section for all the man pages for C and shell would provide a good report

One "gotcha" that varies according to the target is that there are C library man page sections with special names.  An example of this is (3ssl) from the openssl library